# How to display all employees that has different job then previous only in the company in sql?

Tags: sql, oracle

Someone help me. I need to display all employees that has a different job than the previous job in the company only (in SQL).

Comment: Please provide minimum information like table ddl ,small sample data and expected results.

Comment: table employee, job_history. Produce a report to display all the employees that have different JOB_ID than they used to be in the company. Display the entire employee once.

Comment: Make it easy, and possible to assist you: [mcve].

Comment: Sounds like homework. How far have you got? Where are you stuck? Which part of the task do you have a problem with?

Comment: Kind of. But it's not a big homework. I just need to produce output by using set operator in oracle SQL. I need to display all employees that has a different job than the previous job in company using set operator

Answer (score 1):

I would try one of these two (assuming `job_id` keeps the job):

1. `HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT job_id) > 1` should give answer.
2. `LEAD` and `LAG` [functions](https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/lag-lead-analytic-functions)
   give access to next and previous job, so using it you can compare if
   any rows have different values in job id.